# cakephp 3 - exhausted memory in BaseErrorHandler.php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

yesterday, when i was working on a CakePHP 3 application, suddenly i got this error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2291587111384 bytes) in [application directory]\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php on line 109

it tries to allocate 2.2 TB !!! I googled the error and found no one got error like it. the problem is that even the fresh CakePHP application shows the same error !!!

My mind blowing up, any help please :(

Comment: Can you please provide us some more information what you tried to do when this happened?

Comment: I tried to figure out where is the break by using var_dump and exit in CakePHP source code and I found that register_shutdown_function() caused the error. and now I'm try to figure out why this happened (even in fresh created application)

Comment: Have you tried to restart the services or the whole server since this error occurred?

Comment: yes I did, I restated everything. it's really strange. I didn't make any update to apache server or composer or to any component. i suggested that it is a bug but it happened even to my old applications and fresh applications !!!

Comment: btw I found that the problem is not in CakePHP framework, is with the register_shutdown_function(). I tested this function in empty php file and it throw the same error.

Comment: if someone get the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126777/register-shutdown-function-with-anonymous-function-error