# register_shutdown_function() with anonymous function error

Tags: php

I've got a problem and strange behavior while using the register_shutdown_function() function, let me show that by examples:

first using a normal callback function

```
<?php 

function myFunc() { 
    echo 'Function invoked...!'.PHP_EOL; 
};

myFunc();

register_shutdown_function('myFunc');

?>
```

result

> Function invoked...! Function invoked...!

second using a anonymous callback function

```
<?php 

$myFunc = function () { 
    echo 'Function invoked...!'.PHP_EOL; 
};

$myFunc();

register_shutdown_function($myFunc);

?>
```

result

> Function invoked...!  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728
>   bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2291587111384 bytes) in
>   E:\www\test.php on line 9

please any suggestions ???

Comment: Did you try pass the whole function as argument.

Comment: if you meant as in line function, yes I did. actually it is  register_shutdown_function(function () { ... }); in my main script

Comment: This looks like a bug in your php version, which might already be fixed in newer versions. What is the php version you are using? This problem cannot be reproduced on `PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Jan  4 2018 15:30:42) ( NTS )`.

Comment: PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2017 20:56:53)... i guess that it's a bug but everything was ok yesterday, and i did not make any update

Comment: update php to v7.2.1 and the problem is solved :\